# Why is "salient" pronounced with a "long a" sound?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, latin, phonology, vowels, vowel-length

The word *[salient](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salient)* is pronounced with a "long a" sound; Wiktionary gives the US pronunciation as /ˈseɪ.ljənt/, /ˈseɪ.li.ənt/. Is there any reason why the vowel letter here receives its "long" pronunciation (IPA /eɪ/) rather than its "short" pronunciation (IPA /æ/)?

The vowel does not seem to have been long in the Latin ancestor of the word, *[saliens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saliens).* We use a "short a" in the word *[valiant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/valiant)* /ˈvæljənt/, which has the same spelling pattern.

Comment: I have posted and self-answered this to split off some tangential, but in my opinion useful information from my answer to a similar question: [Why do we pronounce a long second vowel in “decide”, but a short second vowel in “decision”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336090) If anyone has more information about this spelling/sound pattern, I'd love to hear it. You can post another answer, or if you just want to add a few exceptions I've missed, you can edit mine (I've made it community wiki).

Comment: One might observe that the 3rd grade pronunciation rule *almost* holds here.  The A is long because it's in an "open" syllable.  (I say "almost", however, since the I is also in an open syllable and isn't pronounced long.)  For "valiant", on the other hand, the first syllable is "closed".

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're linking to Wiktionary? As a ESL/EFL teacher I tell students to avoid both it and Wikipedia. Neither are written by professionals.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: Hmm, if there was I don't remember. I guess I could switch to [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/salient?a=british). Wiktionary is sometimes flawed, but even professionals make mistakes sometimes. I find it to be OK for what it is--a free online dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Lengthening rule for {a, e, o, u} before CiV or CeV

The long vowel in *salient* is caused by a lengthening rule that originally applied in Middle English to stressed vowels followed by a single consonant (not including *x*) and two unstressed vowels. In most cases, the first unstressed vowel was *i*, as it is here, but it could also be *e,* as *ocean*. In other words, the general resulting pattern is **V̄CiV** or **V̄CeV**, where **V̄** represents a long vowel (ā, ē, ō or ū), **C** represents any single consonant letter apart from *x,* and **V** represents any vowel letter. Notably, this lengthening rule did not apply when the stressed vowel was *i*: that was subject to an opposite, shortening rule in this environment (described in my answer to the following question: [Why do we pronounce a long second vowel in “decide”, but a short second vowel in “decision”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/336150/77227))

In Modern English, the unstressed *i* or *e* in these words has often been reduced to a palatal glide /j/ or absorbed altogether by the preceding consonant. However, the stressed vowels remained lengthened. This lengthening rule may also apply by analogy to words with this spelling pattern that were taken from Latin into Modern English.

I found a quite illuminating discussion of this rule, and its historical application, in Otto Jespersen's *[Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles: Part 1, Sounds and Spelling](https://books.google.com/books?id=IQ_HI3WWPF4C&pg=PT181&lpg=PT181&dq=discretion%20companion%20valiant%20special%20precious&source=bl&ots=jVh2aET6U_&sig=rJuvQgQ5hOQHBux6xLsDjBOtHrc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim1NaUt_nOAhWK7SYKHaA0D0EQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=discretion%20companion%20valiant%20special%20precious&f=false)* (1954). *Valiant* happens to be an exception.

### The rule only applies to some types of words

First, a note about the scope of this rule. It only applies to words of Classical origin (ultimately from Latin or Greek, possibly brought to English via French), or in some cases to words where VCiV or VCeV occurs due to the addition of a Classical suffix (such as *-ial* or *-ium*) to a non-Classical base (for example, *nobelium* may be pronounced in accordance with the rule, as *nob**ē**lium,* or with a short “e”, as *nob**ĕ**lium*).

It does not apply to words where VCiV or VCeV occurs within a native English word, or due to the addition of a native English suffix such as *-er* or *-est.*

Example words where the rule does not apply:

- *b**u**rial* < Old English *byrgels*
- *c**ŏ**pier* < *c**ŏ**py* + *-er*: the same would apply to any other verb ending in a short vowel, a single consonant and "y" followed by the suffix *-er* (a hypothetical wrd “studier,” for example)
- *b**u**sier, b**u**siest* < *busy* + *-er, -est*: the same would apply to any other adjective ending in a short vowel, a single consonant and "y" folwd by the suffix *-er* or *-est*

It also doesn’t necessarily apply to un-nativized loanwords that entered English later than the Middle English period, such as *Soviet.* However, in some cases it’s hard to identify loanwords, so I’ll just list them along with the other violations of the rule.

## List of words that violate the VCiV lengthening rule

The first two categories I’ll discuss contain very few words, but they are among the most commonly used words that violate this rule.

**with "short e" before *-ci-*/*-ti-***:

- *discr**ĕ**tion,  pr**ĕ**cious, sp**ĕ**cial.*  Jespersen notes these, but doesn’t explain why they developed differently from other words such as  *mat**ē**rial, imp**ē**rial, sp**ē**cious.* It may just be coincidence, but all of these occur before the sound /ʃ/.

**ending in *-ătional***:

- [*r**ă**tional, n**ă**tional*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62429/why-are-nation-and-national-pronounced-differently). These could be considered to exhibit trisyllabic laxing. In fact, Jespersen says the long vowels in other adjectives ending in *-VCional,* such as *occ**ā**sional, congreg**ā**tional, dev**ō**tional,* are due to analogy with the vowels in the corresponding nouns, rather than regular phonetic development. Despite this history, in Modern English the productive pattern is the one with the long vowel, so these two words can be considered irregular.

The next two categories are larger, and contain some words that are common and others that are quite rare. They consist of words spelled with VniV or VliV. Jespersen says a number of words in this category don’t follow the lengthening rule because in Old French, they had a palatal consonant sound /ɲ/ or /ʎ/ rather than a Ci sequence. A number of other words spelled like this seem to be pronounced with short vowels for unclear reasons, possibly due to analogy.

### before *-ni-*:

- *comp**ă**nion,  **o**nion* (="**ŭ**nion"),  *p**ŏ**niard, Sp**ă**niard, sp**ă**niel.* According to Jespersen, from French words with /ɲ/.
- *b**ŭ**nion.* Jespersen doesn’t mention this word. Its etymology is obscure.
- *gr**ŭ**nion, c**ă**nion.* Both or these are probably from Spanish words with /ɲ/ (spelled *ñ*). The dictionaries I have checked say the usual etymology of the fish “grunion” is from Spanish *gruñón,* and the rare/archaic word "canion" (also spelled “cannion”) is from Spanish *cañon.*
- Proper nouns: *D**ă**niel, Nath**ă**niel, H**ă**niel, **Ă**niel.* These are names from the Bible ("Haniel" is an angel's name). I don’t know how or at what time they received their current English pronunciations.

The remaining words in this category are all unimportant, obsolete, or have alternate regular pronunciations; I’m only listing them for completeness.

1. Two words that end in -ănia, possibly:

   - *Oce**ă**nia* (regular pronunciation also exists). Although this pronunciation is fairly common, there are also pronunciations with “broad a” or “long a”.
   - *Britt**ă**nia.* Variant of Britannia. Likely to be considered a misspelling in modern English, although variation between -t- and -tt- and between -n- and -nn- in this word dates back to Latin. I don’t know if a pronunciation with long a was ever used historically.
2. Three words from French that in modern French have /nj/ rather than /ɲ/

   - *m**ă**nioc.* The modern French word *manioc* actually has /nj/ rather than /ɲ/ (insofar as these sounds are distinguished). However, the OED says the spelling “magnioc” was used (among others) in French in the 17th century, which may indicate past confusion between these sounds.
   - *f**ă**nion.* Rare. From French *fanion,* diminutive of *fanon.*
   - *l**ă**niard.* Alternate spelling of *lanyard.* From French *lanière.*
3. *fr**ă**nion.* Obsolete and rare. Of uncertain origin. Not used in modern times, so I’m not sure how anyone would know how it used to be pronounced, but [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/franion) says /ˈfrænjən/.

### before *-li-*:

- *v**ă**liant, batt**ă**lion.* According to Jespersen, from French words with /ʎ/.  Regularly-pronounced words with similar spelling: *s**ā**lient, Pygm**ā**lion.*
- *It**ă**lian.* Jespersen doesn’t mention this word, but perhaps the same explanation applies here. The OED lists a variety of historical spellings, some of which have *-ll-, -ill-* or *-ly-,* which to me seem to suggest /ʎ/. There are regularly-pronounced words with similar spelling: *Austr**ā**lian, Episcop**ā**lian, Vit**ā**lian.*
- *ret**ă**liation, ret**ă**liate.* French /ʎ/ doesn’t seem like it would be relevant here, since these words were taken from Latin, not French. John Walker (1824) lists the modern, irregular pronunciation, so it doesn’t seem to be a recent thing. According to the OED, the noun *retaliation* is older. It may be relevant that in this word, the vowel only has secondary stress; it seems possible to me that this might inhibit vowel lengthening. There don’t seem to be any other words with similiar spelling to compare these to.
- *t**ă**lion.* ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talion), [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/talion)) Rare, but it seems it did come to English through French. Possibly this explains the pronunciation. Of course, the modern pronunciation could actually be affected by the pronunciation of the related words “retaliate/retaliation”; it’s not clear to me that the historical pronunciation of this word managed to be passed down through oral transmission.

Proper nouns:

- *V**ă**lium.* It’s a brand name, so it’s not too suprising it violates a pronunciation rule. Obviously not from Old French, so /ʎ/ is irrelevant. Possibly influenced by the pronunciation of *valiant.* There is a regularly-pronounced word with similar spelling: *dent**ā**lium.*
- ***Ĕ***liot. A name. I don’t know how it got its current pronunciation. It seems it may come from Scotland originally; it doesn’t seem to be Latinate. There is a variant spelling "Elliot" that corresponds better to the pronunciation.

The remaining words in this category are all unimportant, obsolete, or have alternate regular pronunciations; I’m only listing them for completeness.

- *trisk**ĕ**lion.* This is a synonym of *triskele,* from Greek. Both are very rare. It seems unclear why *-ion* was suffixed to the word. Regularly-pronounced words with similar spelling: *aphelion, perihelion.*
- *Evangeliar*? OED says /iːvanˈdʒɛlɪɑː/
- *Evangelion*? I don’t know the usual pronunciation.
- *glossol**ă**lia.* Only the OED lists this; all other dictionaries I’ve checked give the regular pronunciation *glossol**ā**lia.* I don’t know how the OED determined this pronunciation. It might actually be a mistake.

### Miscellaneous other words:

- *ch**ă**riot, cl**ă**rion.* (Only relevant for speakers without the [Mary-marry merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Mary.E2.80.93marry.E2.80.93merry_merger).) Jespersen says the pronunciations of these words were influenced by now-obsolete synonyms from French, *charet* and *clarine.* There are various other words from Romance languages that are exceptions like this, such as *c**ă**viar* (which the OED says had a stress shift, with a variety of historical forms), *c**ă**meo* (from Italian and French, with a variety of forms), *l**ă**riat* (derived from Spanish “la reata") and *p**ă**tio* (derived from Spanish *patio*).
- *gl**ă**diator.* From the etymology, I would expect this word to rhyme with *radiator*; it’s unclear to me why it does not. (Actually, apparently, for some people they do rhyme, because ["radiator" is pronounced with a short vowel](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/06/radiator.html)!) The same irregularity is present in one pronunciation of the related word *gl**ă**diolus* (the other pronunciation has a stressed long *i* and reduces the vowel of the first syllable; compare the stress pattern of *areola*).
- *g**ă**seous.* The word *gas* is of relatively recent origin. This may explain why the *a* is not lengthened in this adjective.
- one common pronunciation of *r**ă**tion.* There is also a regular pronunciation *r**ā**tion* (with /eɪ̯/) that seems about as common. The pronunciation with "short a" seems like it might be due to influence from the pronunciation of the related word *rational.*
- one common pronunciation of *h**ă**giography.* There is also a regular pronunciation *h**ā**giography,* although it doesn’t seem to be as common. Another irregularity about the pronunciation of this word is that the “g” is frequently pronounced as “hard g” /g/ rather than “soft g” /dʒ/. It seems that the pronunciation with "soft g” only occurs for speakers who use a “long a” in this word.
- the usual pronunciation of *g**ĕ**riatric* (with /ɛ/, /e/ or /eə̯/). According to [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geriatric) and [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/geriatric?s=t), a regular pronunciation *g**ē**riatric* (with /ɪə̯/, /i/ or /ɪ/) also exists, but it does not seem to be common at all.
- one common pronunciation of the prefix *st**ĕ**reo-.* There is also a regular pronunciation *st**ē**reo-*, although it doesn't seem to be as common.
- one pronunciation of *[hyst**ĕ**ria](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hysteria).* There is also a regular pronunciation *hyst**ē**ria* that seems about as common. The pronunciation with "short e" seems like it might be due to influence from the pronunciation of the related word *hysterical.*
- one common pronunciation of *[sacril**e**gious](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00393278508587916?journalCode=snec20)* (="sacril**ĭ**gious"). There is also a regular pronunciation *sacril**ē**gious* (with /iː/), although it doesn't seem to be as common. The pronunciation with short stressed /ɪ/ uses a vowel quality generally associated with the letter "i" rather than with the letter "e", and seems to have arisen by analogy with the word *religious* (although the words are generally not thought to be related etymologically).
- one uncommon pronunciation of *epid**ĕ**miology*; probably due to influence from the related adjective and noun *epid**ĕ**mic.* The regular pronunciation *epid**ē**miology* seems to be more common.
- Another general class of words where “irregular” pronunciations are common is adjectives ending in *-ian,* or nouns ending in *-ium,* derived from proper nouns that end in a single vowel followed by a single consonant. Often these show some variation between a pronunciation with a short vowel (which is presumably felt to be closer to the pronunciation of the independent name) and a pronunciation with a long vowel (presumably by analogy to other words in English with this spelling pattern).
  Examples: the elements *nobelium* and *meitnerium,* and the adjective  *Wagnerian,* have pronunciations with ĕ as well as ē. The adjective *Brobdingnagian* seems to only be pronounced with “short a.” A relevant question: [Adding an L when appending an -ium suffix to a word? (Metallium vs. Metalium)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299015)

---

Additional Sources:

- *[English Grammar for Dutch Schools](https://books.google.com/books?id=JLc3AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=discretion%20companion%20valiant%20special%20precious&source=bl&ots=im8eGXvDso&sig=_-Q6Z9wxr4VaMhCNZ8wozMdDpvg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim1NaUt_nOAhWK7SYKHaA0D0EQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=discretion%20companion%20valiant%20special%20precious&f=false),*
  By C. van Teil, revised by P.C. van Heynsbergen, 1934 (provided list of some words with the spelling _CiV and exceptional pronunciations)
- [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com) (pronunciations and etymologies of some words)
- [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com) (used wildcard search to find some words with this spelling pattern)
- [Phonetic Word Search](http://www.benbriedis.com/phonetic/search.php) (used wildcard search to find some words with irregular pronunciations)

Comment: I am delighted to learn that the way I pronounce sacrilegious follows a rule. In the past I have defended my egregious pronunciation by saying that it helped with the spelling and that reminded me that I was dealing with sacrilege