# "pro" pronunciation in the middle of words

Tags: pronunciation

Is there any rule for pronunciation of the vowel in words like "approximate" or "appropriate"? Why is one pronounced as /ɑ/ and one as /o/? I have searched threads but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Once again, I hate to be the one to tell you, but English spelling does not represent English pronunciation very well. English spelling is a very good fit to Middle English pronunciation, but it hasn't changed much since printing hit England around 1500, right in the middle of the [Great Vowel Shift](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2VowelShifts.pdf). When that ended, English was Modern; but English spelling wasn't. Consequently the answer to all such questions has to be, "no, there isn't any rule; they have to be learned individually". Sorry about that, but it's a painful truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronunciation of the "o" in "approximate" follows the rule that in a stressed syllable, a vowel letter before the letter "x" represents its associated "short vowel" pronunciation. This is similar to how a "short" pronunciation is regular before "ct" which represents the consonant cluster /kt/. In general, when a single vowel letter is used to represent a vowel sound before a consonant cluster that can't occur at the start of a word in English, the vowel sound is "short" rather than "long". Since the letter "x" after a vowel letter represents the consonant cluster /ks/ (or sometimes /gz/, /kʃ/ or /gʒ/), which cannot occur at the start of an English word, the letters "a" "e" "i" "o" "u" "y" are regularly pronounced as /æ ɛ ɪ ɒ ʌ ɪ/ (or /æ ɛ ɪ ɑ ʌ ɪ/ in American English) before the letter "x".

The pronunciation of the "o" in "appropriate" is explained by two rules: the one described in [Why is "salient" pronounced with a "long a" sound?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346984/why-is-salient-pronounced-with-a-long-a-sound) and a rule that certain consonant clusters that *can* occur at the start of words, like "tr", "pr", "cr" and "cl", act the same as single consonant letters for the purposes of vowel letter pronunciation.