# The double "ff" in tariff

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

The term tariff has come a long way before entering the English language. Its derives from Arabic ***ta'rifa***, Italian ***tariffa*** and ultimately from French ***[tarif](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tariff)***:

> - *From French tarif, from Italian tariffa..... from Arabic تَعْرِفَة‎ (taʿrifa)*.

(Wiktionary)

Has  the presence of the double final  *f* something to do with pronunciation given that   the French original spelling consists of only  one single *f*?

Comment: “f” is a letter that is often doubled word-finally in English, like “s” and “[l](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308974/why-is-there-a-double-ll-in-bell)”.

Comment: That entry is wrong. tariff is not a verb. Sometimes I really dislike Wikipedia.

Comment: To 'derive ultimately from' is a fixed expression meaning 'originate with', hence it is incorrect to put X = French in 'it derives ultimately from X'.

Comment: @Lambie But it IS a verb. It's more commonly a noun, though. Also, that's Wiktionary, not Wikipedia...

Comment: Lots of words spelled with double f at the end: staff, sheriff, whiff, toff, riff, miff, off, cliff....

Comment: @Lambie - Your comment is misleading. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tariff) and  [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tariff) also recognize _tariff_ as a verb, as do four of the five dictionaries at [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/tariff). The OED lists it as a verb as well, with this sentence from 1870 as an example usage: _If the siege lasts long enough, dogs, rats, and cats will be tariffed._

Comment: @J.R. Did it every occur to you that this forum says "usage". In all my born days (a lot believe me), I have never ever heard the word tariff used as a verb.  Citing the OED with its 1870 example is not germane to contemporary usage.  Of course, if I saw it in the OED sentence in a book, I would "get" it but what is misleading is to cite dictionaries as if the term were "monnaie courante", as the French say. Tarif comes from Arabic.

Comment: tariffa s. f. [dall’arabo ta῾rīfa, propr. «notificazione, informazione»]. –http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tariffa: from the Arabic tarifa, notification, information. I'll have to tell my tax lady that my jobs are all tariffed.

Comment: @Lambie - what's the point of Treccani link?

Comment: @Lambie - Your comment says nothing about usage. It claimed the entry was "wrong" because "tariff is not a verb." (Had your comment merely said, "Tariff may be listed as a verb, but it's far more often used as a noun," I would have quietly agreed, and perhaps even upvoted the clarifying remark. Instead, you muddied the waters with misinformation.) The OED reference was only meant to show how long the word has been used as a verb; if you prefer a more contemporary example, there's, "He cannot tariff outgoing goods heavily, either." (*Scion of Cyador*, L. E. Modesitt, Jr., Macmillan, 2001)

Comment: @user2922582 To show that it comes from Arabic. It also exists in all the Romance languages. The Spanish Real Academia also says: Del ár. hisp. ta‘rífa, y este del ár. clás. ta‘rīfah, de ta‘rīf 'definición'. So, tarifa from Andalusi Arabic  and tarifah from classical Arabic.

Comment: It is not a verb in contemporary English. Scion of Cyador is a novel. It is not usual usage.

Comment: @Lambie - that is comes from Arabic  “ta’rifa” was stated also in  my question, though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tariff is better. That said, I cannot answer the question of why it takes a double ff.

Comment: @Lambie - as for the double ff,  suggestions here range from imitation of Italian tariffa to imitation of other common ff ending English terms such as staff, whiff, sheriff etc.

Answer (score 3):

The [**OED**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197851?rskey=xHJNx0&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) netry for tariff, noun, gives the etymology as from the Italian originally and this agrees with its first known usage which also relates to the Italian spelling.

**Etymology**

> Etymology: < Italian **tariffa** ‘arithmetike or casting of accounts’ (Florio), ‘a book of rates for duties’ (Baretti), = Spanish tarifa, Portuguese tarifa, < Arabic taʿrīf notification, explanation, definition, article, < ʿarafa in 1st conj. to notify, make known. So French tarif.
>   The word came into general use as a technical term (sense 2), and this character it long retained in English use, being hardly found, except as applied to the Customs ‘tariff’; its more general application (sense 3), found earlier on the Continent and in U.S., has become more common in Great Britain only since c1890.

**Usage**

> †1. An arithmetical table or statement; a table of multiplication, a ready reckoner, or the like.
>   **1591**   W. Garrard & R. Hitchcock Arte of Warre 224   So that helping your memorie with certain Tablei or **Tariffas** made of purpose to know the numbers of the souldiers that are to enter into ranke.

Comment: The entry in the OED appears to support that in both etymology and original usage, yes.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And percent is also from Italian: per cento.  Import tariffs, a specific tax on importing goods into a country. Funnily enough, there's an entire Euro-speak thing with telephone rates, where the word tariffs is misused. Can't be bothered to go into here.

Comment: @user2922582  That would be a moderator decision, not mine.

Comment: Based on sourced statements in the Wikipedia article and at https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/119065/1/TEM1994-3_289-304p.pdf, double-entry bookkeeping emerged from Italy at the end of the 15th century, which would be after the grand wave of borrowing from French into English had ended. And, as Nigel J showed, the OED has "tariffa" first attested in 1591, after the French heyday. So it wouldn't surprise me if some accounting terms came directly from Italian instead of through post-1066 French.